# sudo root cannot find executable on path

Tags: centos, sudo, path, java

I am on CentOS 7.5 and installing OpenJDK 11 from Adopt OpenJDK. It doesn't have an installer package so I am manually putting it in `/usr/share`. I then create the file `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` to set up `JAVA_HOME` and put the java executable on the path. When I run `java -version` from my own account it works fine. When I run `sudo java -version` it says java: command not found. Every time I try to search if someone else has had this problem I just keep getting the responses to create the `/etc/profile.d` file. Any ideas?

This is a fresh install of CentOS 7.5 on an Azure VM.

Comment: Does `sudoers` on Centos use a `secure_path`?

Comment: I don't know. I never heard of `secure_path`. But when I run `sudo echo $PATH` it shows the correct path.

Comment: It will show you your current path because the `$PATH` valuable is evaluated before `sudo` is run. The net effect is that `sudo` sees something like `sudo echo /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/share/jdk/bin`, which isn't what you're trying to do.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm away from my servers at the moment but I'm pretty sure CentOS does.

Comment: @markbernard you might try running `sudo -l` and looking for a line containing `secure_path`

Comment: @steeldriver `secure_path` is there. Is there a way for me to change it? Or is there a more accepted way to give all the Java commands to root? Thanks.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the info. I didn't realize that environment variables were evaluated before the context switch occurred.

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the `/etc/sudoers` to add my path to `secure_path`. Also if you put your answer as and answer I will accept it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to ensure `JAVA_HOME` is set in `sudoers`, too. (Sorry, I can't remember the syntax offhand, but I think the keyword is `env_set`.)

Comment: @roaima Thanks. Will do.

Comment: Did you know that Java 11 OpenJDK is part of CentOS?  Why are you using a package that's not part of CentOS when it's already there?

Comment: Yes I know. The vendor we use at work will only give support if you use the Adopt Open JDK version.